# Can pip access pypi without checking the SSL certificate or can it even use http instead of https?

Tags: python, http, https, ssl-certificate, pip

In my enbviroment I need to use use `pip` via my local proxy (i.e., with the `--proxy` command line option). When I do so I get the error

```
error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

I assume this is due to certificate problems, because my proxy does not support `https` with certificate check , but it does support `https` *without* certificate check. (e.g. `wget https://webpage.com` does work, when I have `check_certificate=off` in the `.wgetrc`.)

So, for the pip problem I figure, when I can tell `pip` not to check certificates it should work. The other option is to tell `pip` not to use `https` at all, but only `http`.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pip with --proxy argument.
pip install --proxy 
http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip.html#cmdoption--proxy
See if the error changes.

Comment: I *do* use --proxy already; I better mention this explicitly in the question.